# Golang sort.Swap Method

Tags: go

I am fairly new to Golang, although I have already written some lines of code. I was exploring the sorting options when I found this<sup>[(src)](https://golang.org/src/sort/sort.go?s=6435:6470#L252)</sup>:

```
func (p StringSlice) Swap(i, j int)      { p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i] }
```

I have no clue what is it going on there. Could someone explain to me what `p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]` is doing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does what its name says: it swaps the i<sup>th</sup> and j<sup>th</sup> elements.

It is an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments), more specifically a tuple assignment:

```
p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]
```

It assigns values to `p[i]` and `p[j]`, and the values that are assigned to them in order are `p[j]` and `p[i]`.

> The assignment proceeds in two phases. First, the operands of [index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [pointer indirections](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) (including implicit pointer indirections in [selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)) on the left and the expressions on the right are all [evaluated in the usual order](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation). Second, the assignments are carried out in left-to-right order.

Comment: Now I see it!! My eyes were seeing p[i] | p[j] = p[j] | p[i] and I was like "what is the point of assigning p[j] to p[j]". Thank you for pointing out the TUPLE assigment.

Answer (score 0):

here in golang, we dont need a tmp variable. 
It will assign directly with line
p[i], p[j] = p[j], p[i]

it is one of miracles in golang
Enjoy!